# I lost my keystore, I can't upgrade my app in the market

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

I upload my first app into market, and now I want to upgrade a new version, but I got this exception when I upgrade my app. " The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version."
I lost my certificate keystore, what can I do in this situation? unpublish my app and rename the package? 
Can I upload other app using the other keystore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faced the same problem. I was trying to restore it via deleted files restoring tools, but it failed. So, there is no other way: you should issue another application.

Of course, any other your application you can upload with other certificate. It is used only for the security purposes: to ensure that upgrading person is the one who is the author.

Generally, the only advise that exists on keystores: always backup it!

Comment: Thank you Vladimir Ivanov !:)