# How can I upload apk with new version, when previous key store is lost?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: I lost my android key store, what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)

I have lost the key store that I used to sign apk previously. I know key store holds private key and google never had it. 
I had to make backup of it. But now when I lost it is there any way to come out of this situation.

Please help.

Comment: Check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322367/i-lost-my-keystore-file/4322386#4322386  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470183/i-lost-my-keystore-i-cant-upgrade-my-app-in-the-market

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have lost the keystore file, unfortunately your only recourse is to create a new one and change the app's package name.  Google Play will not accept an APK if it is signed with a different keystore than the one used when the app was originally uploaded.

You can change the package name of your app and create a new listing on Google Play, this time signed with the new keystore.  Unpublish the old listing and notify users that they will need to re-install the app via the new Google Play listing.

Comment: Thanks Anidamo for you answer. Can you please tell me the way how can I notify users.

Comment: I did not lost keystore but it says`"Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"`. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

> I have lost the key store that I used to sign apk previously. But now
>   when I lost it is there any way to come out of this situation.

=> There is **no chance at all**. If you wanted to update your application, you have to have that keystore by which you have sign up and released 1st version of app.